# how do you map a sub domain to a directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, subdomain, subdirectory

I current have 2 asp.net mvc websites set up in azure as follows:

www.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com

however I am after the sub domain to be accessed and displayed as www.domain.com/subdomain/ but I cannot figure out what I must do to achieve this

do i need to edit the web.config of both or just the subdomain and if so to what?

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: `www.domain.com/subdomain` is not actually a subdomain. Just a directory off the root, from the client's perspective. On the server, you can map a virtual application there.

Comment: thanks for your input. If I create a virtual directory called subdirectory and set the physical path to site\wwwroot\subdirectory how do I publish or route my current website subdomain.domain.com to it?